# C# Form and Python Interop

Tags: c#, python, interop, winforms-interop

I am trying to find a way to interact with a C# form from a Python script. Is this possible? Currently I am creating my form using IronPython, however, I would rather create them using C#.

Comment: Would you still be using IronPython to execute your Python code or not?

Comment: @JustinNiessner To be honest, I am not sure. The python scripts I write are extensions of scripts written for the application. I believe it is IronPython, but I am not sure how to check to verify that.